# Neo4j embedded database doesnt show the browser in a spring boot app

Tags: neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

[update] Please find the config classes here : https://github.com/veeseekay/fooflix.
To run, you can just do a 

`gradle clean build
java -jar build/libs/fooflix.jar`

When you point to localhost:8686 - gives a 404. However, I am running this within my IDE and the browser shows up fine.

I have successfully embedded neo4j within my spring boot application. I could even bring up the webadmin/browser for neo4j using this :
[How to enable neo4j webadmin when using spring-data-neo4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883424/how-to-enable-neo4j-webadmin-when-using-spring-data-neo4j)

However there is a weird problem which am not able to figure out. When I run this spring boot application in my IDE, am able to access the neo4j webadmin from the browser and view the graphs, however, if I build an uber jar and run it on a terminal, am not able to access the webadmin. I get a 404.

```
<code>
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /browser/. Reason:
    Not Found
Powered by Jetty://
</code>
```

looks like a path issue, but am not able to figure out why. any pointers would be of great help.

here are my gradle deps

```
<code>
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
compile("org.springframework:spring-context")
compile("org.springframework:spring-tx")
compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:3.4.0.RELEASE")
compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator")
compile("javax.el:javax.el-api:2.2.4")
compile("javax.el:javax.el-api:2.2.4")
compile("org.neo4j.app:neo4j-server:2.2.5")
compile("org.neo4j.app:neo4j-server:2.2.5:static-web")
</code>
```

thanks

Comment: Can you share any exceptions that might come up in the console or graph.db/messages.log ? It could be that your uber-jar merges META-INF/service declarations not correctly.

Comment: thats the weird part again, i dont see any error messages on the console. The messages.log says this 
`<code>`
2015-09-27 05:12:04.222+0000 INFO [o.n.s.w.Jetty9WebServer]: Mounting static content at [/browser] from [browser] 2015-09-27 05:12:04.775+0000 INFO [o.n.s.WrappingNeoServer]: Server started on: 127.0.0.1:8686 2015-09-27 05:12:04.775+0000 INFO [o.n.s.WrappingNeoServer]: Remote interface ready and available at [127.0.0.1:8686/]`</code>`

Comment: please rather update your question. Can you share your config classes to?

Comment: Alright, this prob is fixed by unpacking the neo4j browser in the uber jar. I had to include this in my build.gradle
`springBoot {
    requiresUnpack = ['org.neo4j.app:neo4j-browser']
}`

thanks @micheal